# Custom Dialog in tkinter

Tags: python, popup, tkinter, customdialog

I am trying to make a custom popup dialog box using Tkinter in Python.
By custom I mean having several buttons with the text I want.
The closest to what I am trying to do is this code

```
from Tkinter import *
from Dialog import Dialog


class OldDialogDemo(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        Pack.config(self)  # same as self.pack()
        Button(self, text='Pop1', command=self.dialog1).pack()
        Button(self, text='Pop2', command=self.dialog2).pack()

    def dialog1(self):
        ans = Dialog(self,
                     title   = 'Popup Fun!',
                     text    = 'An example of a popup-dialog '
                               'box, using older "Dialog.py".',
                     bitmap  = 'questhead',
                     default = 0, strings = ('Yes', 'No', 'Cancel'))
        if ans.num == 0:
            self.dialog2()

    def dialog2(self):
        Dialog(self, title='HAL-9000',
                     text="I'm afraid I can't let you do that, Dave...",
                     bitmap='hourglass',
                     default=0, strings=('spam', 'SPAM'))

OldDialogDemo().mainloop()
```

(source: Programming Python by Mark Lutz 4th edition published by O'Reilly Media, Inc.)
My problem is that I cant find any documentation on it. BTW why is it old dialog? is it deprecated or something?
PS. I found out that if I import tkMessageBox the above Dialog does not appear?? does that have to do with the old part?